# Navigation css issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

In Dreamweaver here is the output of navigation bar design:

**http://postimg.org/image/li0uprb9f/**

When I browsed in Firefox this is now the out put the navigation. Sigh... this is so confused...

**http://postimg.org/image/wnktsxwyf/**

This is my code:

```
#navbar {
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    right: 45px;
    top: 50px;
}

#ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your list has no id="ul". Remove the # in front of the ul in your css code.

Comment: add list-style-type: none; to the ul ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#navbar {
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    right: 45px;
    top: 50px;
}


#navbar ul li {  /* ADD #navbar infront*/
    float:left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Also.. you should check out this guide:
http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Comment: when i adjust my padding why another div is also moving..? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use these rules for the navigation list:

```
ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: If you change the display I would recommend to set it to inline-block and remove the float.